# Dialog без открытия активити

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-dialog

Задача такая. Имеется сервис, который работает постоянно, в том числе и тогда, когда все активити приложения закрыты. Он шлет данные в класс приложения, который не уничтожается при закрытии активити. Этот класс ждет сообщений от сервиса. И когда сообщение приходит, он должен инициировать открытие диалога, не привязанного ни к какому активити. Возможно ли и как это сделать? Или возможно, сам service может создать диалог?

Comment: Вам нужен именно диалог или просто вьюха тоже подойдёт?

Comment: На крайний случай можно и вьюху, а как ее показать без активити? Я думаю, диалог проще.

Comment: Вы можете запустить активити [с темой диалога](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979631).То есть стартуете активити, на экране она будет выглядеть как диалоговое окно.

Comment: А как стартовать активити из простого класса? Наспимер, если я там сохраню ссылку на Application, смогу я оттуда активити старотовать?

Answer (score 1):

Отобразить к-л вьюху из сервиса можно так:

1. Получаем объект-экран в который будем добавлять вьюхи

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

2. Добавляем в него программно созданные вьюхи методом `addView(View v, LayoutParams params)`

```
windowManager.addView(view, params);
```

3. В манифесте указываем нужное разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Comment: А где взять инфлатер для создания вьюшек? Годится какой-нибудь от старого активити, которого уже может и нету?

Comment: И что задать в качестве params?

Comment: инфлатер просто из контекста берите `LayoutInflater.from(context)` а параметры... Наверное любые, типа `new LinearLayoutParams(100, 100)`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно сделать прозрачный `Activity` со стилем типа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

из которого уже "родить" `Dialog`

Comment: Если активити, то как его стартовать из класса, который не активити?

Comment: Для запуска `Activity` требуется только наличие `Context` из которого стартует `Intent`. `Service` имеет контекст так что никакой проблемы в старте активити из сервиса не существует

Comment: В этом примере найдете ответ. Там реализована плавающая кнопка по рабочему столу как в мессенджере fb. https://github.com/trinhlbk1991/DemoAndroidFloatingView